# Why my concated videos resulting in fps drop?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have one main .mp4 video and several logo .mp4 videos. I manage to create python script that eventually called `ffmpeg.exe` to create duplicate of that one main .mp4 video into distinct ..mp4 video with different logo

Problem is, sometimes (I think if the file size is in more than 1GB) the generated video resulted in audio that plays sooner than the video. This is my command to produce that concatenated video:

`ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i "{file_list_name}" -c copy "{target_file}" -y`
file_list_name is .txt file with content such as:

```
file 'logo1.mp4'
file 'main.mp4'
```

Both of the file already in the same resolution: 1080p

Comment: Check that all logo files have audio, and they should have same properties as audio of main file.

Comment: There is. Woa. This should be the case then. I will try removing the audio to be safe

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the case. Removing the audio, and concatenating it, the resultant file grows into 2.5GB in which the original file was just 70Mb, with fps drop like it is in frame by frame mode.

Comment: Hi @Gyan: your comment solved my problem. Which is I simply remove logo file. It works. Logo is actually optional. I create duplicate movie, with addition of logo + text watermark. This text watermark alone solved my issue. So, if you willing to move your comment to answer section, I will accept that. Thanks!